# Degradation of sympy det function performance when applied to large matrices of polynomials

Tags: python, sympy

This occurred after upgrading sympy (1.0->1.1.1) and mpmath (0.19->1.0.0).

`poly_mat = eval(poly_mat_str)
det = poly_mat.det(method="berkowitz")`

where `poly_mat_str` is the string repr for some complex polynomial matrix (examples at link below). The degradation is observed as vastly increased resultant det size and calculation times. Note that smaller polynomial matrices do not seem affected, see the ticket for more information.

The table below shows changes on my machine to the calculation times and resultant det sizes for three polynomials, which can be found here: [example polynomials](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/files/2303670/good_poly_matrix.zip)

[image]

Comment: It would be better to open this in the [SymPy issue tracker](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/new). Also, please include some code that can reproduce the error, as well as the full traceback (not just the last line).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes, I plan to work on a complete description and reproduction for your tracker. It seems dependent on the size of the polynomial matrices I'm using. Also I'm seeing longer calculations with latest, sometimes appears to get stuck. I am having to publish my project with older sympy and will be locked to this until fix.

Comment: We are very busy with publication atm and good reproduction will take time. So could be in a month before I can create this issue.

Comment: https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/15086

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to a change that came about following a sympy refactor (apparently). Polynomial matrices need to be created using the PolyMatrix type. The following code will work on both 1.0 and 1.1.1:

```
try:
    from sympy.polys.polymatrix import PolyMatrix as sym_matrix
except ImportError:
    from sympy.matrices import Matrix as sym_matrix
```

And then create your matrix using `sym_matrix`.